# Drupal login destination is ignored when members log in

Tags: drupal, civimember, user-account

When members log in, they are always redirected to their Drupal user profile page, and the login destination in the URL is ignored.

For instance, when they try to access a members-only page, they are prompted to login, but after they do, instead of returning to the page they were accessing, they are send to their user profile page.  This does not happen to non-members who have a Drupal account, where they are redirected as specified in the URL.

We do have LoginToboggan and LoginDestination modules installed, but they do not seem to have anything to do with this behavior.  Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I use the [r4032login](https://www.drupal.org/project/r4032login) module. I find that it often fixes issues where users hit a login-in CiviCRM page, then redirects them correctly back.

Comment: Thanks-- I installed that module, but was not able to apply any settings that helped in the situation.